# How to access main object's property inside inner nested object?

Tags: javascript, this, javascript-objects

```
let obj = {
  a: "Kale",
  b: "kite",
  c: "citay",
  d: "dantay",
  allNames: {
    name1: obj.a,
    name2: obj.b,
    name3: obj.c,
    name4: obj.d
  }
};
```

> error:Cannot access 'obj' before initialization

I want names in `allNames` object to be equal to values in outer `object(obj)`, i.e.

```
name1: "kale"
name2: "kite"
name3: "citay"
name4: "dantay"
```

If I do it with `this` method:

```
allNames: {
    name1: this.a,
    name2: this.b,
    name3: this.c,
    name4: this.d,
}
```

Of course it'll be undefined .. so how to do this and not to make it look like hard-coded?